# Powershell Testing the values in a combobox

Tags: powershell, combobox

I am trying to test if a combobox contains values and if it doesn't then execute some code. The combobox should always contain two values which are version numbers in the form 7.xx.xxx.xxx
Here is what I have so far....

```
function GetAvailableVersions{
    if ((Get-Variable UpdateNewVersionCombo).value.Items.ToString() -notlike 7){
        $ProdVersionNumber = (Get-ChildItem '\\172.20.10.18\home$\BuildCopier V7 Prod\Optima.exe').VersionInfo.FileVersion
        $GetProd = ($ProdVersionNumber.ToString())
        (Get-Variable UpdateNewVersionCombo).Value.Items.Add($GetProd)
        $DevVersionNumber = (Get-ChildItem '\\172.20.10.18\home$\BuildCopier V7 Dev\Optima.exe').VersionInfo.FileVersion
        $GetDev = ($DevVersionNumber.ToString())
        (Get-Variable UpdateNewVersionCombo).Value.Items.Add($GetDev)
    }   

}
```

The function GetAvailableVersion is called when the selected index of another combobox is changed. When it is called for the first time it adds the version numbers to the combobox as expected, but when the index of the first combobox is changed the test on the current values fails and the version numbers are added to the combobox again, resulting in the versions being duplicated.
Please can someone shed some light on how to test the combobox for already containing values that start with 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call the `Items.Clear()` method, to clean out the combo box's values, before adding the replacement values. That's what I generally do for UI code that populates values into a multi-item control, such as a ComboBox or ListView, etc.

If you want to test for the existence of an item in a `ComboBox`, you'll have to first determine what type of object was added to the `ComboBox`, and then perform a comparison on the appropriate property. If all you're doing is adding `String` objects to the `ComboBox`, then it's easier.

Here is an independently functioning example using a common, yet complex object, the `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

```
# Get a list of processes
$ProcessList = Get-Process;
# Create the ComboBox
$ComboBox = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox;
# Clear all items from ComboBox
$ComboBox.Items.Clear();
# Add Process objects to ComboBox
$ProcessList | % { [void]$ComboBox.Items.Add($PSItem); }


# Test if ComboBox contains a process named Notepad
$ComboBox.Items.Name -contains 'notepad';
# Result: $false

# Test if ComboBox contains a process named System
$ComboBox.Items.Name -contains 'System';
# Result: $True
```

Comment: Hi Trevor, Thank you for the advice, it is really appreciated. That will work, but would mean every time the selected item of the first combobox is changed then the code would be executed regardless, whereas I am really looking for a solution that will test if the second combobox contains any values and execute the code if there is no values present.

Comment: @DogManDave: Hey Dave, I updated the answer with a comparison example.

Comment: That's great! Many thanks! Should do the trick as the values are file version numbers cast as strings and will always start '7.'. Am I correct in assuming I can use a wild card in the 'contains' value? i.e `$ComboBox.Items.Name -contains '7.?'`

Comment: If you want to use a wildcard (regex), you'll have to use the `-match` operator. The `-Contains` operator only works with exact matches. Keep in mind that the `-match` operator works different with single strings vs. arrays of strings. Do some experimentation with this separately, before you try to combine the WinForms and regex matching.